# Using grep to search for a string that has a dot in it

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to search for a string `0.49` (with dot) using the command

```
grep -r "0.49" *
```

But what happening is that I am also getting unwanted results which contains the string such as `0449`, `0949` etc,. The thing is linux considering dot(.) as any character and bringing out all the results. But I want to get the result only for "0.49".

Answer (score 351, accepted):

`grep` uses regexes; `.` means "any character" in a regex.  If you want a literal string, use `grep -F`, `fgrep`, or escape the `.` to `\.`.

Don't forget to wrap your string in double quotes. Or else you should use `\\.`

So, your command would need to be:

```
grep -r "0\.49" *
```

or

```
grep -r 0\\.49 *
```

or

```
grep -Fr 0.49 *
```

Comment: I needed to escape twice like so `\\.` for it to work.
I'm using zsh.

Comment: @NikosRenieris did you wrap your grepping string with double quotes?

Comment: @JustusRomijn I think I did, yeah.

Comment: you'll need to use `\\.` for bash too, or use `"\."` to escape it from the shell.

Comment: none of these solutions worked for me, running in zsh

Comment: @VelocityRa only `\\.` worked for me in bash.

Answer (score 40):

`grep -F -r '0.49' *` treats 0.49 as a "fixed" string instead of a regular expression. This makes `.` lose its special meaning.

Answer (score 25):

You need to escape the `.` as `"0\.49"`.

A `.` is a regex meta-character to match any character(except newline). To match a literal period, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 15):

There are so many answers here suggesting to escape the dot with `\.` but I have been running into this issue over and over again: `\.` gives me the same result as `.`

However, these two expressions work for me:

```
$ grep -r 0\\.49 *
```

And:

```
$ grep -r 0[.]49 *
```

I'm using a "normal" bash shell on Ubuntu and Archlinux.

*Edit,* or, according to comments:

```
$ grep -r '0\.49' *
```

Note, the *single*-quotes doing the difference here.

Comment: You need to quote the regex from the shell, or escape the backslash itself so the shell doesn't consume it. `grep '\.'` or `grep \\.` (I would strongly recommend the former. Double quotes work, too, as in the original question; but single quotes are easier to understand and use. For example, with double quotes, you'd still need to double the backslash in some scenarios).

Comment: IMHO, this is the clearest correct answer, with the comment of @tripleee it is the most complete.
the use of [ ] (which functions to represent a subset of characters to match a single character to) is a nice hack.

Comment: @jringoot Seriously? I think this isn't clear at all -- it looks more like a follow-up question from someone who wasn't familiar with quoting.

Comment: It is clear because both expressions work directly and indeed many others assume the quoting or need to double escape to avoid secondary interpretation by the shell as trivial. 

I can't change the comment anymore (5 minutes limit). My comment might have been better:
"this, if  combined with the comment of @tripleee it is the most complete answer. Because both commands work immediatly and with the quoting it is complete"

Comment: What I usually recommend is "always single-quote your regular expressions". It's not "complete" but it gets the job done and implies you either need to understand quoting or live by this simple rule.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use "[.]"

```
grep -r "0[.]49"
```

Comment: using egrep this was the only option I was able to get to work

Answer (score 6):

Just escape the `.`

`grep -r "0\.49"`

Answer (score 5):

Escape dot. Sample command will be.

```
grep '0\.00'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the dot and other special characters using \

eg. grep -r "0\.49"

Comment: A reminder to future reader, `\.` surround with quotes is necessary to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also search with -- option which basically ignores all the special characters and it won't be interpreted by grep.

```
$ cat foo |grep -- "0\.49"
```