# I wanted to grep specific pattern from file

Tags: grep

Continents of file

```
Yasir.txt
Yasir1.txt
<txt>
Nothing 
</txt>
```

If i use grep command

```
grep ".txt" file
```

I'm getting

```
Yasir.txt
Yasir1.txt
<txt>
</txt>
```

I'm expecting

```
Yasir.txt
Yasir1.txt
```

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep to search for a string that has a dot in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346816/using-grep-to-search-for-a-string-that-has-a-dot-in-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use

```
grep "\.txt" file
```

regards

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to improve this answer, please explain why this works and the ops original not.

Comment: grep use regular expression to find patterns.
the dot mean "1 char". if you want to have a 'dot', you need to escape him with a \

Answer (score 2):

Using a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -n '/\.txt/p' file_name
```

I think answer of @DavidP seems more convenient using `grep`:)

Comment: capture group is redundant here.. `sed -n '/\.txt/p'` is enough.. and using sed here instead of grep is inefficient

Comment: @Sundeep: yes, i agree with you that `grep` is more convenient here. Thanks for your comments. Maybe i can edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Perl regular expression of grep?

```
grep -P ".txt$"
```

Comment: that would work without `-P` too.. OP issue was not escaping the `.` meta character... also, as a good practice, always use quotes, otherwise it would be subject to shell interpretation as a glob pattern

Comment: @Sundeep Thank you for your comment, I updated my answer.